# Ansible fails task with template containing special character

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a logstash configuration template that gets populated through group_vars. While I add the below grok pattern

```
 kv {
         source => "[message]"
         allow_duplicate_values => false
         remove_char_key => "\\\""
         value_split => ":"
        field_split_pattern => "\,"
         target => "modsec"
          remove_char_value => "\\\""
         include_brackets => false
      }
    grok {
      match => { "[modsec]{data}" => '\{%{GREEDYDATA:p_data}\}'}
      remove_tag => ["_grokparsefailure"]
      add_tag => ["modsec_audit"]
     }

    kv {
     source => "p_data"
     field_split => ":"
     target => query
    }
```

Ansible template tasks fails on the line

```
match => { "[modsec]{data}" => '\{%{GREEDYDATA:p_data}\}'}
```

How to escape the line ?

When I copy the value of `'\{%{GREEDYDATA:p_data}\}'` to ansible variable as given below :-

```
logstash_grok_value: "'\'{%{GREEDYDATA:p_data}'\'}"
```

It errors out as ...

> "template error while templating string: tag name expected. String:"

When I use escape character instead of using variables in

```
match => { "[modsec]{data}" => \'\\\{\%\{GREEDYDATA:p_data}\\\}\'}
```

It errors out as

> This one looks easy to fix.  It seems that there is a value started
>   with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
>   with the same kind of quote

My ansible task for logstash is as given below:-

```
- name: Create configuration files in conf.d
  copy:
    dest: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/{{ item.name }}.conf"
    content: "{{ item.config }}"
    owner: "{{ logstash_user }}"
    group: "{{ logstash_group }}"
    mode: 0755
  with_items:
     - "{{ logstash_input_output_config }}"
  notify:
    - Restart logstash
```

and the logstash_input_output_config has the details of 
logstash_input_output_config:

```
- name: mdg-config
  config: |
        ### INPUTS ###
        input {
         kafka {
              bootstrap_servers => "{{ logstash_kafka_hosts_list }}"
              client_id => "{{ inventory_file | basename }}-wafnginx-audit"
              topics => "topic-secaudit-nginx"
              type => "topic-secaudit-nginx"
              codec => json
              fetch_max_bytes => "7242880"
          }
        filter {
            if [type] == 'topic-seaudit-nginx' {
            kv {
              source => "[message]"
              allow_duplicate_values => false
              remove_char_key => "\\\""
              value_split => ":"
              field_split_pattern => "\,"
              target => "modsec"
              remove_char_value => "\\\""
              include_brackets => false
            }
           grok {
             match => "[modsec]{data}" => "\{%{GREEDYDATA:p_data}\}"
             remove_tag => ["_grokparsefailure"]
             add_tag => ["modsec_audit"]
           }
          }

        }
```

Expected result is task should be completed to success.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding the unsafe option.

```
logstash_grok_value: !unsafe '\{%{GREEDYDATA:p_data}\}'
```

Notes:
Ansible provides an internal data type for declaring variable values as “unsafe”. This means that the data held within the variables value should be treated as unsafe preventing unsafe character substitution and information disclosure.

Jinja2 contains functionality for escaping, or telling Jinja2 to not template data by means of functionality such as `{% raw %} ... {% endraw %}`, however this uses a more comprehensive implementation to ensure that the value is never templated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The unsafe option worked. It complains when used within list of multiple items. When we use a plain template file, it works fine. For example, if ansible uses templates with replacable file from an element of list, it complains. !unsafe works fine with templates based on plain file.

Comment: thats great, please mark the answer as solution if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. In the context of usage of unsafe, I am restricted as the replacable array/hash has ansible variable in it.

As a result I would need to use either {% raw %} {% endraw %} or {{ \" \" }}.

While I use  '{% raw %}{% endraw %}{% raw %}{{% endraw %}{% raw %}%{% endraw %}{GREEDYDATA:p_data}{% raw %}{% endraw %}{% raw %}}{% endraw %}'

It displays "\{%{GREEDYDATA:p_data}\}" instead I just need "{%{GREEDYDATA:p_data}}"

When I use '{% raw %}{% endraw %}{% raw %}{{% endraw %}{% raw %}%{% endraw %}{GREEDYDATA:p_data}}}'